# Facebook Javascript SDK - Fb.login not working on Facebook built in browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I Noticed that Facebook FB.Login function or Facebook Login button are no longer working on pages that are opened using Facebook's in app Browser on Android. ( When the user clicks the URL inside the Facebook App, and it opens on the app built in browser ). On Messenger it is working right.

I don't know when this bug started. I have tested using even FB.login function and also with Facebook Login Button ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button ). Got the same result for both of them. It just refresh the page.

Sample code:

```
<script>

function LoggedFb(){
       //This is just a sample code. This code when executed from a URL opened from Facebook's Browser ( When user clicks on a url on the Facebook App ), won't run. From Chrome or other browser works fine.
    alert("got in here");
}

</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-onlogin="LoggedFb" data-use-continue-as="false" data-scope=""></div>

</html>
```

The sample above, when ran on Chrome for example, will work normal and call LoggedFb function. When a page with this code is ran from the Facebook built in browser, it will just refresh.

I have tried also implementing FB.Login functions but it does not work either.

I have even filled a bug report ( https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/456215991739392/) 
 but they say this is not a bug.

Since this started I've seen a lot of websites with broken login buttons. Anyone else experiencing this, or have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try if implementing a [manual login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) yields any more successful results. (You can use that purely client-side, check the explanation of the `response_type` parameter.)

Comment: But even then, that would give you a token only so far - I'm afraid it might not lead to the JS SDK recognizing a logged-in user in this situation afterwards either. In that case, you could still make your own API calls by explicitly supplying the token as parameter manually (I don't think it has a method to _set_ a default access token from the outside) - but other stuff that depends on recognizing a logged-in user internally might still not work properly.

Comment: @valter Any fix for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @sagar43. Only solution was to implement manual login flow using php. Facebook app is bugged. Since few days ago sharing stopped working also on android.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever access is coming from the Facebook Mobile Browsers. Clicking FB.login does nothing because it already assumes you're logged in. What you need to do is use the current accessToken and userID of the logged in account to get the details that you need using FB's API.

Here's a code sample for Javascript:

```
signInWithFB(): void {
FB.getLoginStatus((response: any) => {
  if (response.status !== 'connected') {
    return FB.login((response: any) => {
      this.handleResponse(response)
    }, {
      scope: 'public_profile,email',
      enable_profile_selector: true,
      auth_type: 'rerequest',
      return_scopes: true
    });
  } else {
    this.handleResponse(response)
  }
});
}

handleResponse(response) {
FB.api(`/me?fields=email,picture,first_name,last_name`,
  (response: any) => {
    this._loginService.socialLogin({
      email: response.email ? response.email : '',
      profilePicture: {
        'url': response.picture.data.url,
        'key': ''
      },
      fullName: `${response.firstName} ${response.lastName}`,
      socialId: response.id,
      ...FACEBOOK_LOGIN
    }).
      subscribe(res => {
      })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*whenever you are using FB.login or FB.getLoginStatus methods you need to call them using the onlogin attribute of the fb button for eg:*

`<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="fblogIn();"> </fb:login-button>`
instead of using the :
`<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-onlogin="LoggedFb" data-use-continue-as="false" data-scope=""></div>`

*and this won't be able to call the login method so try using the fb:login button and pass the login method name in onlogin="" attribute
hope this helps you*